# Is there a way to auto refresh function documentation in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

As we all know, code keeps changing constantly. Someone creates it and then thousands of people will change the parameters of the functions and underlying code. The function parameters that are documented keeps changing.

For example, the function documentation looks like this now:

```
/**  
 * Updates the email of the user to the new one.  
 *  
 * @param type $new_email  
 * @param type $session    
 * @param type $security_key  
 *  
 * @return type
 * @throws Exception_SessionExpired  
 */  
public function update_email($data)
```

Of course it is not reflecting the current function params, worse, there are many more like this :(

How to update all function documentations in a file easily in one shot? Like for formatting according to code conventions, there is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Is there any such thing in NetBeans to update documentation too?

Answer (score 2):

I just type `/**` before the function declaration and press enter. Then just reorder as needed.

Comment: Then you'd lose the description of function and parameter descriptions if there are any...

Comment: @Shrinath I never said delete the original one, create a new one, and just move the params to the old one.

Comment: @Shrinath yea. You get what you pay for.